# Bootstrap - drop down within mobile menu opens fine, cannot close drop down

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

Here's the site: https://paperfibresinc.wpengine.com/

Site requires a login to see, here are the creds:

User: demo
Password: paperfibresinc

If you're on mobile and click on the Services navigation menu item, it opens up the drop down which is perfect. However, when you try to close the Services menu by clicking on the word Services again, nothing happens.

Any idea why?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_dropdowns.asp ... follow this link , if you are using bootstrap use data-toggle="dropdown" and other data- attributes

Answer (score 0):

It's beacause you use css to show dropdown:

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

If you want to hide dropdown-menu on click you can you bootstrap component dropdown. Just remove this css and add `data-toggle="dropdown"` to Services link, and style your dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

remove this

CSS

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

and add this HTML

```
<a title="Services" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Services <span class="caret"></span></a>
```

hope this helps..